# Открытие файлов при помощи Process и "обвал" приложения. Как исправить?

Tags: c#

Запускаю файл при помощи Process. Если нет программы открывающей этот файл, приложение "обваливается". Как это исправить?

```
Process.Start(fileName);
```

Comment: try/catch пробовали? Что за ошибка то?

Comment: @tym32167, просто пишет что не найдено приложение способное открыть данный тип файла. А потом приложение закрывается с ошибкой

Comment: Какое приложение закрывается с ошибкой? Которое главное или которое запустить пытаетесь?

Comment: я пытаюсь открыть файл. Чтобы его открыть нужна прога. (*doc  - Office Word). Такой нет. Соответственно идет ошибка и закрывается **главное** приложение. А так блок try-catch решил проблему. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно вставить процесс в try-catch